# find: combining -path and -prune to exclude files and directories

Tags: bash, find

I have a directory `/srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg` and a file `/etc/mtab`. I want to exclude both from `find`. But whatever I do, either one always is not excluded

```
find /etc /srv -path /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg -prune -o \! -path /etc/mtab
find /etc /srv \( -path /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg -prune -o -print \) -a \( \! -path /etc/mtab \)
```

Note: I find the `-path /foo -prune -o -print` syntax highly confusing and unintuitive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
$ find /etc /srv \( -path /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg -o -path /etc/mtab \) \
    -prune -o -print
```

This will "prune" either of those 2 `-path` arguments from the list, and print everything else.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
find . \! -path "./.git*" -a \! -name states_to_csv.pl
```

so converting to your should be something like

```
find /etc /srv \! -path "./srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg*" -a \! -name /etc/mtab
```

The -a flag stand for "and".